# How to avoid incurring a cache miss in multiprocessing cases

Tags: python, caching, python-multiprocessing

I have been spending time on a Python script designed to move data from some type of store (SQL, NOSQL, S3) to another transforming it on the go. The amount of data that needs to be transformed and transferred will often be around hundreds of Terabytes in other words hundreds of files containing billions of rows. Under this scale with current setup, reaching a completion was taking nothing less than 20+ hours.

Employing a comprehensive enough approach I was able to progress to 8- hours and the way I have achieved that was to create a new process per entity being loaded into memory and also maintain as many target connections (in this case it was a SQL database) as possible. Moreover, since the language was Python, I had to assign a new thread to each connection considering the infamous "Global Interpreter Lock" in place.

Its a known fact that having excessive number of threads won't deliver you the equal level of boost in terms of performance so I had to find the most convenient number (It was 3 threads per process). In addition to thread limitation, target's ability to perform optimally under such a load was a contributing factor as well. (target CPU occupancy was around 90% during the application frame with 20 processes and 60 open connections in total, each connection sending insert queries containing 1000 rows)

However, I am inclined to believe that through low level optimisations, one should be capable of attaining an occupancy higher than 90%. What I had in mind initially was to minimize the cache misses that were hypothetically occurring due to the fact that each process was receiving a Queue object generated by a Manager. The purpose of this queue was to simply establish a channel between the parent and child processes and perform the relevant actions based on the output of queue. (Logging, process shutdown etc.). Having this queue shared amongst multiple processes, raised the concern of performant utilization of cache since a push into the queue should presumably trigger an invalidation across multiple processors. (Not sure if message queues are implemented in this way, thats another question)

Does having a single queue for communication with all the processes pose a risk towards cache coherency if so, Could having a dedicated queue per process solve the problem at all ?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.